# に満ちた and particles に　が

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-が

> 溢れ出す魔力は、もはや抑えが利かない。
>   **一の回路に満ちた十の魔力**は、その逃げ場を求めて基盤を壊し―

に満ちた=full of.
感情に満ちた顔=A face full of emotions.

In the sentence at the beginning this construction does not make much sense:

> Ten units of Magic full of 1 circuit look for an escape and break through the foundation.

But I also found an example:

> 香りが部屋に満ちる
>   The smell is filling up the room.

So the sentence in the beginning becomes:

> Ten units of magic which fills a single circuit look for an escape and break through the foundation.

Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think this is some novelistic writing, so you might want to give more about the context, but here's what came up in my mind:

> 一の回路に満ちた十の魔力

Actually, 〜に満ちた here is **not** "full of."
Both に are `case particles`, but my understanding is that に in 一の回路に満ちた十の魔力 **indicates the place the following thing exists** - it acts like "in." But に in 感情に満ちた **indicates the subject of the state** (満ちた.)
So This is actually "**10 magic filling 1 circuit.**"

By the way, what would happen if you forcibly try to pack 10 balls into a box which can hold only 1 ball? The box would break. 1 and 10 are depicting such a situation. **The circuit can handle 1 *unit* of magic, but 10 units of magic tried to go through it.**

> **魔力は、その逃げ場を求めて基盤を壊し**

So that magic of 10, couldn't be fit into the circuit with a cap of 1, broke the *foundation* seeking for the place to escape.

So the rough translation will be:

> 10 units of magic packed into the circuit with the capacity of 1 broke the foundation seeking for the place to escape.

---

*Below is my additional interpretation. **It might be wrong depending on the context of the sentence.***

But think about it - if it's not really the *magic* that is breaking the *foundation* (because the sentence seems to be from some novel,) what is it? *Huge amount of magic bursting out of **circuit** that can't hold them and breaking the **foundation**?*
If the context is right, I believe 魔力 is referring to **electricity!** And if 基盤 is referring to the **circuit board,** that makes perfect sense - like this.

> Electricity 10 times bigger than expectation packed into the circuit broke through the circuit board, seeking for the place to escape.

I think the people involved somehow screwed something up while building the circuit and when they turned it on, current 10 times bigger than their expectation ran through the poor circuit, and sparked through the board, rendering it completely useless.

Comment: Yeah, Magic is kinda like electicity in this scene.  
Could you tell me why "に満ちた" is not "full of" but it means "filling"?  This is a relative right? Its not relative form is
"一の回路に十の魔力が満ちた" or am I wrong?

Comment: @Splikie Both に's are `case particles.` But it's use is different. My understanding is that に in 一の回路に満ちた十の魔力 indicates the place the following thing exists - it acts like "in." But に in 感情に満ちた indicates the subject of the state (満ちた.)

Comment: That is what I was thinking too. I tought it could be like 溢れる. "僕が気合に溢れる"; "僕に気合が溢れる". Is the same right? In the first one に means "by", in the second one "the place".

Comment: Well, 溢れる does hold the problem like みちる. But 僕が気合に溢れる sounds weird because in this case, I think が "wins" against に and becomes the `case particle` for the subject. So it means something like "I fill" (?) I looked at the Japanese corpus, and it looks like that if you use が with 溢れる, it doesn't mean "filled with" anymore. It's pretty much always used as a part of modification units, like 気合いに溢れたxxxx.

Comment: I see. It was in an old Anki deck of mine. It was kind of weird at that time but I ended up accepting it.

Comment: @Splikie Oh wait a minute. Scratch that. There were nothing wrong in both case! 溢れる's subject should be something that can be counted/measured such as water (水が溢れる), things (物・人が溢れる), and even emotion (感情が溢れる), but **not** specific person. So に changes its meaning depending on the position (僕が気合に vs 僕に気合が)

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at the numbers as units of the same material. The material in this case being "魔力".

So "一の回路" means "a circuit of 1 unit (of magic)", while "十の魔力" means "10 units (of magic)".

The meaning is:

> When ten units are added to a circuit with a capacity of one...

or

> When a circuit with a capacity of one is filled with ten units...

---

As for the difference in meaning depending on the ordering - I feel that it would make sense to say both "回路に満ちた魔力は" and "魔力に満ちた回路は". They mean different things, however.

> 回路に満ちた魔力は
>
> The magic that filled the circuit
>
> 魔力に満ちた回路は
>
> The circuit that was filled by magic

I guess technically, there might be a case where you would want to say "the magic that was full of circuits" (as opposed to a magic not containing any circuits), but generally, the container and containee are obvious. Any rare ambiguity would have to be explained in context.

Comment: So the first one in a non relative form would be: "回路に魔力が満ちた" and the second one "回路が魔力に満ちた". Am I wrong?

Comment: @Splikie that sounds about right. I guess technically, there might be a case where you would want to say "the magic that was full of circuits" (as opposed to a magic not containing any circuits), but generally, the container and containee are obvious. Any rare ambiguity would have to be explained in context.